# JavaScript: How do you expand dotted strings into a nested object that includes arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to expand a flat object of simple key/value pairs to a fully nested object, where the keys are a dotted string index into the fully expanded object (exception: brackets would need to be added to array indices to be used as keys).

Essentially, I would like to convert a flat object like:

```
let groceryStorePrices = {
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.name": "Aldi",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.name": "Milk",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.unit": "gallon",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.price": "$3.00",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.name": "Cheddar Cheese",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.unit": "lb",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.price": "$5.28",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.name": "Apples",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.variety": "Honeycrisp",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.unit": "lb",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.price": "$1.29",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.name": "Potatoes",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.variety": "Russet",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.unit": "5 lb bag",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.price": "$2.58",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.name": "Hy-Vee",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.name": "Milk",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.unit": "gallon",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.price": "$3.40",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.name": "Cheddar Cheese",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.unit": "lb",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.price": "$4.76",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.name": "Oranges",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.variety": "Navel",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.unit": "lb",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.price": "$1.51",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.name": "Potatoes",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.variety": "Red",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.unit": "5 lb bag",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.price": "$2.48",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.name": "Lunds & Byerlys",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.name": "Milk",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.unit": "gallon",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.price": "$3.50",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.name": "Cheddar Cheese",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.unit": "lb",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.price": "$4.98",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.name": "Apples",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.variety": "Honeycrisp",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.unit": "lb",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.price": "$1.34",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.name": "Potatoes",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.variety": "Russet",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.unit": "5 lb bag",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.price": "$2.70",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.0": "Cub Foods",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.1": "Hornbacher's",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.2": "Sun Mart Foods",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.3": "SuperValu",
  "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.4": "WholeFoods"
}
```

to the following expanded object:

```
{
  "foodSupplyChain": {
    "supermarkets": [
      {
        "name": "Aldi",
        "sections": [
          {
            "name": "Dairy",
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "Milk",
                "unit": "gallon",
                "price": "$3.00"
              },
              {
                "name": "Cheddar Cheese",
                "unit": "lb",
                "price": "$5.28"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Fruit & Vegetables",
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "Apples",
                "variety": "Honeycrisp",
                "unit": "lb",
                "price": "$1.29"
              },
              {
                "name": "Potatoes",
                "variety": "Russet",
                "unit": "5 lb bag",
                "price": "$2.58"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Hy-Vee",
        "sections": [
          {
            "name": "Dairy",
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "Milk",
                "unit": "gallon",
                "price": "$3.40"
              },
              {
                "name": "Cheddar Cheese",
                "unit": "lb",
                "price": "$4.76"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Fruit & Vegetables",
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "Oranges",
                "variety": "Navel",
                "unit": "lb",
                "price": "$1.51"
              },
              {
                "name": "Potatoes",
                "variety": "Red",
                "unit": "5 lb bag",
                "price": "$2.48"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Lunds & Byerlys"
        "sections": [
          {
            "name": "Dairy",
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "Milk",
                "unit": "gallon",
                "price": "$3.50"
              },
              {
                "name": "Cheddar Cheese",
                "unit": "lb",
                "price": "$4.98"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Fruit & Vegetables",
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "Apples",
                "variety": "Honeycrisp",
                "unit": "lb",
                "price": "$1.34"
              },
              {
                "name": "Potatoes",
                "variety": "Russet",
                "unit": "5 lb bag",
                "price": "$2.70"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
    toAdd: ["Cub Foods", "Hornbacher's", "Sun Mart Foods", "SuperValu", "WholeFoods"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was working on this problem, I wasn't able to find a version that handles arrays, so here's what I came up with:

```js
let groceryStorePrices = { "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.name": "Aldi", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.name": "Milk", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.unit": "gallon", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.price": "$3.00", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.name": "Cheddar Cheese", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.unit": "lb", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.price": "$5.28", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.name": "Apples", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.variety": "Honeycrisp", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.unit": "lb", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.price": "$1.29", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.name": "Potatoes", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.variety": "Russet", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.unit": "5 lb bag", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.0.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.price": "$2.58", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.name": "Hy-Vee", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.name": "Milk", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.unit": "gallon", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.price": "$3.40", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.name": "Cheddar Cheese", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.unit": "lb", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.price": "$4.76", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.name": "Oranges", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.variety": "Navel", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.unit": "lb", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.price": "$1.51", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.name": "Potatoes", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.variety": "Red", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.unit": "5 lb bag", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.1.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.price": "$2.48", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.name": "Lunds & Byerlys", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.name": "Milk", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.unit": "gallon", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.0.price": "$3.50", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.name": "Cheddar Cheese", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.unit": "lb", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.0.Dairy.items.1.price": "$4.98", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.name": "Apples", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.variety": "Honeycrisp", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.unit": "lb", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.0.price": "$1.34", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.name": "Potatoes", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.variety": "Russet", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.unit": "5 lb bag", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.2.sections.1.Fruit & Vegetables.items.1.price": "$2.70", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.0": "Cub Foods", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.1": "Hornbacher's", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.2": "Sun Mart Foods", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.3": "SuperValu", "foodSupplyChain.supermarkets.toAdd.4": "WholeFoods" };

const dottedStringsToObject = ( object ) => {
  return Object.entries( object ).reduce( ( o, [ k, v ] ) => setValue( o, k, v ), {} );
};

const setValue = ( object, path, value ) => {
  const keys = path.split( '.' );

  keys.reduce( ( o, k, index ) => {
    if ( !isNaN( Number( keys[ index + 1 ] ) ) && !o[ k ] ) { o[ k ] = []; }
    else if ( index + 1 === keys.length ) { o[ k ] = value; }
    else { o[ k ] = o[ k ] || {}; }
    return o[ k ];
  }, object );

  return object;
};

console.log( dottedStringsToObject( groceryStorePrices ) );
```

You can use the following version of `setValue()` to obtain a better understanding the code:

```
const setValue = ( object, path, value ) => {
  const keys = path.split( '.' );
  let keysTraversed = [], currentPath, newNode;

  keys.reduce( ( o, k, index ) => {
    keysTraversed.push( k );

    if ( !isNaN( Number( keys[ index + 1 ] ) ) && !o[ k ] ) { o[ k ] = []; }
    else if ( index + 1 === keys.length ) { o[ k ] = value; }
    else { o[ k ] = o[ k ] || {}; }
    
    newNode = o[ k ];
    currentPath = keysTraversed.join( '.' );
    console.log( `${ index } ${ currentPath }:`, newNode );
    return newNode;
  }, object );

  return object;
};
```

Comment: Note: In the example, all of the values are strings, but the solution also handles values that are themselves objects or arrays.